# How to prevent duplicate entry in registration activity

Tags: java, android

I would like it that when a user registers a username in my app if that username is already taken that he/she will get a toast saying "Username is already taken".

I already included the UNIQUE constraint in my Database and it works fine but in the activity itself I would like to let the user know that the Username they are trying to register already exist.

```
    package com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Register extends Activity {
    EditText UsernameReg, PasswordReg, PasswordConfirm, EmailReg;

    Button Register;

    DBAdapter db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        // get Instance of Database Adapter
        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();

        // Get reference of views.
        UsernameReg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UsernameReg);
        PasswordReg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PasswordReg);
        EmailReg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EmailReg);
        PasswordConfirm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PasswordConfirm);

        Register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Register);
        Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Username = UsernameReg.getText().toString();
                String Password = PasswordReg.getText().toString();
                String PassConfirm = PasswordConfirm.getText().toString();
                String Email = EmailReg.getText().toString();
                String TakenUsername = db.getData();

                // Check if any of the field are vacant.
                if (Username.equals("") || Password.equals("") || PassConfirm.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vacant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }
                // Check if both passwords matches
                if (!Password.equals(PassConfirm)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (Username.equals(TakenUsername))

                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Already Taken",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Save data in database
                    db.insertPlayer(Username, Password, Email);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Login"));
                }
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: @StinePike With the method I'm trying to use when I register a duplicate username it still acts on my else statement of redirecting to the Login Activity when I want the 2nd if statement of not going to the Login activity and telling the user the Username already exist to take effect instead.I know I'm using the method wrong (If (Username.equals(TakenUsername) I posted this question to ask what would be the right method.

Comment: chech availablility of the username in the database, I think this is the better solution

Comment: @StinePike How would I do that in code on this class?That's the question I'm asking.Is my statement right?Would I have to use equalscontents instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (Username.equals(TakenUsername))

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Already Taken",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            } else {
                // Save data in database
                db.insertPlayer(Username, Password, Email);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Login"));
            }
```

You can do this

```
long id = db.insertPlayer(Username, Password, Email);
if (id == -1)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Already Taken",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

where

```
public long insertPlayer(String Username, String Password, String Email)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("USERNAME", Username);
    values.put("PASSWORD", Password);
    values.put("EMAIL", Email);

    return db.insertWithOnConflict(Table name, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);  

}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you!By the way I fixed the problem from last night thanks for the BasAdapter example you gave me!

Comment: I had the inflater as r.id.listitems instead of r.id.adminlistitems completely overlooked that one lol

Answer (score 0):

check your database table if the username exists. you can do the following

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { USERNAME},
        USERNAME+ " ='" + userName + "'", null, null, null, null);
        if(c.getCount > 0)
               username taken;;
```